# Gparted can't create partition table

Tags: partitioning, gparted, mbr

Here's what the problem is.

About a day or so ago I used Gparted live cd to create 3 NTFS primary partitions on my external 500 gig Goflex and one extended with 2 logical partitiones.

I had planned to install windows 8 on the first partition, then ubuntu and kubuntu on the other 2.

After I finished partitioning my drive with gparted, I booted into windows vista to make my bootable windows 8 usb to install it with, I also decided to check to make sure all my partitions were working properly.

Then I found they were, and they weren't.

My 50 gig first partition I had planned to install windows on showed up normal and the 300 gigs of space left in the extended partition did as well, the rest showed up as raw.

So I figured alright, something went awal while making the partitions, so I booted up gparted once again.

Then to my surprise gparted showed the entire drive as unallocated, and when I refreshed the list, it showed as all the partitions I had made earlier, buy with a exclamation mark by them all.

So I figured ok, might be a problem with the partition table as I'd seen a similar problem in past on a drive that was not partitioned at all, so I decided to create a new partition table and take the time out again to sit and wait.

Then I got a message saying gparted could not create the partition table, followed by it showing the entire drive as formatted into ntfs.

After that I figured ok I'll take a break, come back in a hour, maybe it's something I did.

So a hour later I came back after having booted up windows, plugged the drive in to see if by some miracle windows could access the drive.

In disk management when I plugged the drive in, it would freeze attempting to read the drive, as I'd seen in the past with raw disks, yet when I unplugged it I got a glimpse of disk management showing it as a perfectly fine ntfs file system on the drive followed by a "you must format disk K in order to use it".

So I then was assured the disk was raw as that is what had happened in the past, followed by a new partition table through gparted to fix the problem and a 10 hour format in windows.

So I once again booted up gparted, to get the message "error fsyncing/closing/dev/sdg:input/output error" followed by "error opening dev/sdg No such file in directory" after I refreshed and somehow saw the disk show up as perfectly fine ntfs and then tried to create a new partition table to try to wipe out all my problems and start over again.

And not gparted only shows the drive there about 1/10 refreshes the rest I get the directory error.

If anybody can assist me in any way shape or form I will be thankful.

Comment: I am not sure but I think Windows can't recognize extended volumes properly. U should install Windows on primary partitions.

Comment: Although you intend to eventually install Ubuntu, it seems to me this question isn't really about Ubuntu in any way. You're using a GNU/Linux distro--the GParted Live CD (which is not Ubuntu). And you're getting stuck on creating partitions that you can then see, especially in Windows. This question is probably off-topic for Ask Ubuntu. If you still need help, this would probably be more appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Maybe a HDD error? Try run a smart scan on the disk.

Comment: Ubuntu should never be installed on NTFS. Change the kubuntu and ubuntu partition's filesystem to ext4!

Comment: What you're seeing isn't normal. Maybe check the livecd? (md5/sha256 or other checksums, linux livecds normally have an integrated function to do that)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you create so many NTFS partitions in the first place? As for your info, Ubuntu/Kubuntu can't be installed on one of those, they require a Linux file system like ext4.

I'd suggest the following:

1. Delete all partition.
2. Use Vista to create a primary NTFS partition for Windows8, and then proceed installing it.
3. Install Ubuntu and Kubuntu. You can create partitions for them inside the installer.

Comment: That's the thing, I have been attempting to delete the partitions and create a new partition table but I can't gparted can't even do it.

Comment: Any particular reason to insist using Gparted? It doesn't seem to work very well for you.

Comment: It was working fine till now, any it's the only partitioning software that has worked well for me before.

If you know of a better partitioning software, I'll try it out.

Comment: Try using fdisk. It's command line but it's not that bad. It has a very detailed menu.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to try:

Plug your external hdd.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
fdisk -l
```

*Suppose your disk is /dev/sdg, continue running:*

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdg bs=1M
gparted
```

By gparted create a GPT partition table.

If your PC is (U)EFI aware via the BIOS, create a first partition EFI bootloader `(ef00 EFI System)` `500 Mg`

If your PC is not (U)EFI aware via the BIOS, create a first partition  BIOS boot partition, `(ef02 BIOS boot)` `500 Mg`

A continuation of this partition, leave `80 Gb free`, to install Windows 8.

Then create partitions for swap `(8200 linux swap)` and shared /home 
`(8300 Linux filesystem)` ext4, (using same username and password) to Ubuntu and Kubuntu.

And then finally create partitions for each /,`(8300 Linux filesystem)` ext4, to  Ubuntu and Kubuntu.

The installation of these systems requires that you install  first Windows 8 on free space before the other systems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe zeroing out the MBR could help? `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512 count=1`. I don't know how to do it for a GPT disk. After that, you could try the command line way: create the partition table in `parted` and then create the partitions with `mkfs -t type /dev/sdXn`.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 comes with a protected partition for security reasons. I believe it's called `EUFI`. You need to disable the protection in the BIOS (usually something like <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F11</kbd> at bootup.) This is the only thing you need to do in order to remove Windows 8 completely and install Ubuntu...

However, if you wish to dual boot, you need to be ready to work - because it's hard work. Take a look at [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Dual-Boot-Ubuntu-and-Windows-8-UEFI/) tutorial at intructables.com which I used to dual boot my newly bought laptop. I later on downgraded to Windows 7 by the way.

Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you install a [persistent] live system with mkusb according to these links

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[Compressed image file with a persistent live system with mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Compressed_image_file_with_a_persistent_live_system)

and

- first wipe the first megabyte on the problematic drive with mkusb.
- then run `gparted` and create the partitions you want, or let the installer of the operating system do it, if you are not sure how to do it with `gparted`.

If you want to dual boot with Windows, install Windows first, and install Ubuntu afterwards. Otherwise Windows will 'hi-jack' the bootloader location at the drive head end and you have to re-install the grub bootloader.